# Method Through Reflection is Not Allowed after Applying Sitecore Hotfix

Tags: untagged

I have applied the recent hotfix from [Sitecore security bulletin SC2023-003-587441](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1003018) in my solution and deployed it, but I am getting the following error `while publishing the Sitecore Items`.

[image]

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Calling *********.****.sitecore.shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm.StartPublisher method through reflection is not allowed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException: Calling *********.****.sitecore.shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm.StartPublisher method through reflection is not allowed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[AccessDeniedException: Calling *********.****.sitecore.shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm.StartPublisher method through reflection is not allowed.]
   Sitecore.Reflection.MethodFilter.Filter(MethodInfo method) +1167
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.GetMethodCommand(String command) +701
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Dispatch(String command) +35
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +144
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +806
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After investigation, I get to know that, This Security Hotfix might add a security layer that prevents the execution of unexpected methods through reflection.

As I have customized the publishing method for Sitecore items, I am getting this issue while publishing the Sitecore items.

**Solution:**

1. Go to the path `\App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\` and open the
   `Sitecore.Reflection.Filtering.config` file.
2. Add the method name to
   the `Sitecore.Reflection.Filtering.config` file:

```
<allowedMethods>
         <!--Example:
        <descriptor type="SampleNameSpace.MyClass" methodName="MyMethod" assemblyName="MyAssembly"/>
          -->
    <!--your allowed methods-->
    <descriptor type="{assemblyName}.sitecore.shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm" methodName="StartPublisher" assemblyName="{assemblyName}"/>
</allowedMethods>
```

3. Add a method pattern to the `Sitecore.Reflection.Filtering.config` file:

```
<allowedPatterns>
      <pattern value="^Sitecore\..*,Sitecore\..*$"/>
      <!--your allowed patterns-->
      <pattern value="^{solutionName}\..*,{solutionName}\..*$"/>
</allowedPatterns>
```

Where the `value` is a regular expression matched against the method name string in the format `NameSpace.Class.Method, AssemblyName`.

See the blog post for more details: [Error: Method Through Reflection is Not Allowed after Applying Sitecore Hotfix](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/07/method-through-reflection-is-not-allowed-sitecore-hotfix.html)